# How do I append text to the end of a select option's text using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<select id="dept">
<option value="1" selected>General</option>
<option value="2">Payment Problems</option>
</select>
```

In this instance I want to change `General` to `General (current)`. The option text is also dynamic. I just want to append `(current)` at the end of the option text.

How would I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it always the word `(current)` no matter which is selected?

Comment: Yes, I always want to add `(current)` after the option text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way

```js
$("#dept option[value='1']").append(' (current)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dept">
  <option value="1" selected>General</option>
  <option value="2">Payment Problems</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, I marked yours as the answer since it uses jQuery. int11 also posted a good option to use in regular JS as well.

Comment: @JDel Thanks ...and yes, s/he did

Answer (score 2):

This is a slight improvement to the original answer by @LGSon. This version makes sure "current" is always appended to the currently selected option (I assume the "Value" attribute remains the same when the selection changes):

```
$('#dept option[selected=""]').append('  (Current)');
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```js
var current_text = $("#dept :selected").text();
$("#dept :selected").text(current_text + " (current)");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dept">
<option value="1" selected>General</option>
<option value="2">Payment Problems</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I was hoping there was some way you could do `+= " (current)"` sort of you how can do `document.getElementById("element").innerHTML += "value to append"` in JS. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select').change(function(){
var valu = $(this).val();
var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
text += ' (current)';
$(this).find("option:contains('current')").each(function(){
var txt = $(this).text().replace('(current)','')
$(this).text(txt);
});
$(this).find('option:selected').text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dept">
<option value="1" selected>General</option>
<option value="2">Payment Problems</option>
</select>
```